# У якому стилі можна використовувати слово "бурки"?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники

Знаходжу у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8) значення терміну без зазначення, в якому стилі слід використовувати:

> **Бурки** — різновид теплих чобіт для холодного клімату.

Отож роблю висновок, що воно літературне. Аби переконатися, заходжу в [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/burky), однак там його не знаходжу.

Отож це літературне слово, чи варто використовувати його лише у певному стилі? Якщо так, то буду вдячна за вказівку на стиль вживання слова "бурки".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У сучаснішому [«Словнику української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=153126&page=222) (фактично, наступнику СУМ-11) слово *бу́рки* вже є.

Хоча наявність слова в одному словнику (тим більше такому, що викликає певну критику в мовознавців) може переконати не кожного. Є, втім, воно і на [«Словниках України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) (що, однак, мають того самого укладача  — Український мовно-інформаційний фонд). Є воно й у [«Великому тлумачному словнику української мови»](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8) (іншого укладача, який, однак, навертає на себе не менше критики, ніж СУМ-20).

Мене, однак, більше тривожить не репутація словників, а наявність у різних словниках (зокрема старих) окремого слова *бу́рка* в різних значеннях: бурий кінь, тип плаща (ймовірно, початково часто бурого кольору), тип капюшона (ймовірно, часто бурий), картопля. Складається враження, що *бу́рка*/*бу́рки* — це щось буре, а що саме — залежить від популярності різних речей (і наявності в них окремих назв) у певному історичному періоді — якщо стануть у майбутньому популярними комунікатори певного виробника бурого кольору чи персональні ро́боти бурого кольору чи ще щось бурого кольору, то будуть вони бурками. На скільки часу закріпиться слово *бурки* за типом чобіт (який в Україні, можливо, й не дуже використовується — хоча мені невідомо) — мені незрозуміло.

Але принаймні хоча б формально це слово в словниках зафіксоване.

Answer (score 5):

Звернувши увагу на час створення сторінок у Вікіпедії, роблю висновок, що українська сторінка була створена шляхом перекладу з російської ([російська](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%91%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8&action=history) створена у 2011, [українська](https://uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%91%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8&action=history) - у 2014, до того ж вони майже однакові за змістом).

Звертаємося до російського [Тлумачного словника Єфремової](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/144081/%d0%91%d1%83%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8) - бачимо, що воно таки літературне. А от щодо нормативності вживання цього слова в українській мові я сумніваюся. Підозрюю, що такий тип взуття на території України не використовувася, але можу помилятися.